# Integrating Apollo to meteor app

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

When I'm trying to integrate an apollo server to a meteor app I get errors as soon as I try to open graphiql. If I create an express app and connect it with `webapp.connectHandlers`, and put apollo server to one of that express app's routes, thing work, but they don't work in "meteor way", which I would really like to have, since I would get access to the user object, authorization etc.

Error, which I see in graphiql as soon as it loads:

`Error: Schema must be an instance of GraphQLSchema. Also ensure that there are not multiple versions of GraphQL installed in your node_modules directory`

stacktrace:

`at invariant (/Users/.../node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:18:11)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.validate (/Users/.../node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:59:72)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at doRunQuery (/Users/.../node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:88:38)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/.../node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runQuery.js:22:54<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /Users/.../.meteor/packages/promise/.0.10.0.borizy.o9z8++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40`

server code:

```
import {makeExecutableSchema} from 'graphql-tools';
import {typeDefs} from './schema';
import {resolvers} from './resolvers';
import { createApolloServer } from 'meteor/apollo';

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

createApolloServer({
  schema
});
```

Everything seems legit and works with express, but not with meteor. What is the reason? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of `meteor/apollo` is out of date with the latest apollo npm packages. https://github.com/Swydo/ddp-apollo is up-to-date and does the integration in a "meteor way"

Comment: ddp-apollo is not an option because I wanna gradually switch from meteor, ddp and all that crap, that's why migrating to ddp-apollo doesn't make much sense, since I'll end up using almost the same thing. Maybe you have an idea about exact problems, which are causing my errors so I could fix myself?

Answer (score 0):

> Also ensure that there are not multiple versions of GraphQL installed in your node_modules directory

If this is the problem, it would be solved by

```
rm -rf node_modules/*
npm install
```

Comment: I have double-checked - I don't have multiple versions of graphql. There's only one version, I've also tried yarn's resolutions to make sure that even if by any chance there would be multiple versions, only one would be used - no dice(